# tkinter - "ImportError: the specified module could not be found" python 3.5.1

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having issues running a tkinter program in python 3.5.1, and I really don't understand what's going on. It's never been a problem prior to this point, but now when attempting to run the program in question, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joe/PycharmProjects/Physics2-0/Physics2-0.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled python 3.5.1 to make sure that everything was set back to the default  way it's supposed to be and was when I started developing the program, because I thought I might have messed something up while trying to work with `cx_freeze`, and as far as I can tell, everything is as it was before, when the program worked. I have no idea what changed. The import statements for the program in question are below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solve
```

Any and all help is appreciated. I'm at a loss for how to go forward.

EDIT 1: This is getting weirder and weirder. After running the tkinter test like I said in the comments that I did, I tried running the program, and now it will run. I have no clue why.

EDIT 2: The plot thickens. I created a setup.py for `cx_freeze` to make another attempt at creating an executable of the program. I set my tcl and tk libraries manually as `c:\python35\tcl\tcl8.6` and `c:\python35\tcl\tk8.6`, respectively, and tried to build the executable. It seemed like it worked, but when I ran the executable, it gave me the same error message as it did above, but in a popup error message box, not console. I then tried to do the tkinter test in a python console again, and now when I try `import _tkinter` I get an error message saying `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` I don't think my computer has ever confused me this much. Someone please help.

Comment: What OS are you running? Some OS's don't have tk installed or configured by default (OS X comes to mind)

Comment: @Delioth I'm running windows 10. I haven't upgraded my OS or anything since the program last worked(which I believe was yesterday or the day before), and tkinter always worked before. I worry that I accidentally did some kind of black magic to my installation while trying to make an .exe of the program with `cx_freeze` that somehow didn't get reset when I reinstalled.

Comment: if you have a file named tkinter.py you need to rename it, do you have tkinter installed ?

Comment: @WalleCyril tkinter is in the standard library

Comment: @Delioth For the record, I've tested tkinter in a python console using the steps given in the docs. first `import _tkinter`, then `import tkinter`, and then `tkinter._test()`. When I do that, there are no errors and the test thingy works like it's supposed to. But for whatever reason, if the program tries to import `_tkinter` when it's needed because I have a `from tkinter import *` statement in my program, then it won't work.